# Apache Allow Directory Listing in all subfolders but not the root folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow directory listing in all sub folders inside folder root, but the root folder should not be able to be directory listed. but i wish to do this with just 1 htaccess file in the root folder, not having to place a Options +Indexes htaccess file in each sub folder.. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this is to create an index file in the root folder. If you do not have an index file, you can use mod-rewrite, the following rule in your htaccess to deny directory listing for the root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=403,L]
```